# How to convert Hashtable to array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, object, hashtable

I want to convert this hashtable into array or object. is any php method available to convert hashtable into array or object or anything else.

```
<hashtable>
  <entry>
    <string>actiontypedesc</string>
    <string>Deletion of IP Address [148.56.25.133] from Child Nameserver ns4.pankajwelcome.com</string
>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <string>entityid</string>
    <string>61389936</string>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <string>actionstatus</string>
    <string>Success</string>
  </entry>
</hashtable>
```

Comment: this might help you : http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php

Answer (score 3):

This looks a lot like XML, which is why you could use PHP's SimpleXML extension:

```
$hash = '<hashtable>
  <entry>
    <string>actiontypedesc</string>
    <string>Deletion of IP Address [148.56.25.133] from Child Nameserver ns4.pankajwelcome.com</string
>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <string>entityid</string>
    <string>61389936</string>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <string>actionstatus</string>
    <string>Success</string>
  </entry>
</hashtable>';

$asXML = new SimpleXMLElement($hash);
var_dump($asXML);
```

This creates an object and you can easily access its fields.

Answer (score 0):

A generic conversion will not provide the best result. XML is a data structure, a generic conversion usually results in the loss of information and functionality.

If you like to read this specific data into a simple array, you can use DOM+XPath:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$array = [];
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/hashtable/entry') as $entry) {
  $key = $xpath->evaluate('string(string[1])', $entry);
  $value = $xpath->evaluate('string(string[2])', $entry);
  $array[$key] = $value;
}

var_dump($array);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["actiontypedesc"]=>
  string(82) "Deletion of IP Address [148.56.25.133] from Child Nameserver ns4.pankajwelcome.com"
  ["entityid"]=>
  string(8) "61389936"
  ["actionstatus"]=>
  string(7) "Success"
}
```

`/hashtable/entry` returns a list of all `entry` nodes. `string[1]` would return the first `string` element child node (in a list), but the function `string()` casts it into a string.